# XCode build error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_FIREmailAuthProviderID"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, cocoapods

I have been trying to integrate **FirebaseAuth** based on following guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui

As I only have enabled **Sign-in with Google**, I have added pods like,

```
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
```

And installed Pods from Terminal.

When Pods get installed properly, I opened workspace, cleaned build (also removed contents from DerivedData) and tried to build the app for Simulator which gave me error and my build failed.

```
Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FIREmailAuthProviderID", referenced from ...
```

Full error log and screenshot is attached below.

[image: Full error log]

I have also tried to integrate full Pod, like,

```
pod 'FirebaseUI'
```

That too gave me build errors.

I have tried other solutions available online but this library is integrated via CocoaPods and few online solutions are not applicable to my scenario. However, I have not yet reached to any solution for the issue.

Please let me know if there is any solution to this issue or not. I will also try to integrate this framework manually.

I am using XCode 12.

Comment: see this answer:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on this issue comment: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/928

pointing to latest pods resolved the issue.

Like,

```
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth', '~> 8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

First try it...**

I had the same issue with Carthage, but I resolved it.

Please check if the PromisesObjc.framework is added to your project (make sure the correct target is selected). In my case it wasn’t because I believe this is a new framework they’ve added recently. It goes without saying that “Do Not Embed” should be selected under Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content”.

**Second try it...**

pod file in Framework and Library section add this :- Accelarate framework

Clear derived data and run app

I hope this helps, let me know

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: what is the `PromisesObjec.framework`? I have swift code and added this Firebase Auth library via Cocoa Pods.

Comment: @PareshThakor Please refer Link:- https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/5201/605037614
it's also include FirebaseInstallations in include. please update your pod file.

Comment: pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit/Swift'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit/Swift'

this all pod install in include PromisesObjec.framework