# Cocos2dx Firebase CPP without Pod Integration

Tags: c++, ios, firebase, cmake, cocos2d-x-4.0

I want to integrate Cocos2dx v4 cpp project with Firebase (I am using firebase_cpp_sdk_8.11.0).  This has been successfully integrated in Android.  The problem that I am facing right now is integrate with IOS (without Pod).  I already followed this link https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-use-firebase-in-ios-games-written-in-c-fef1a6a9f87d and official Google Firebase tutorial but still failed.

The step that I did was:

1. Create a new project Cocos2dx with command

```
cocos new CocosFirebase -p <com.your_company.your_game> -l cpp -d .
```

2. Download the firebase_cpp_sdk and put inside the folder (follow the tutorial made a folder third_party). Modify the CMakeLists.txt and add this code below

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/firebase_cpp_sdk)
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME}
    firebase_analytics
    firebase_messaging
    firebase_app
)
```

3. Run the cmake and try to build the project (inside the Xcode is also can).  Without section 2 above, the project can be built successfully.  With Firebase code in CMakeLists.txt, it failed with error below (error build both in simulator or product any ios device arm64 amv7).

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_app.a(app_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_app.a(app_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UNUserNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_messaging.a(messaging.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_app.a(app_ios.mm.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessaging", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfirebase_messaging.a(messaging.mm.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried to link the library needed as stated in here [Firebase Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64) but no luck.  Or tried also to link directly inside the xcframework that provided from firebase cpp sdk.

Please note that I have successfully integrate with Android, and due to complexity and issue with Pod, I would like to integrate directly since Firebase also provide CPP SDK.

Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue with my project using the Qt framework.

It looks like you're only using the firebase-cpp SDK.

This issue seems to be relative : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk/issues/19

You might miss the native FirebaseIOS libs which the firebase-cpp-sdk wraps: https://firebase.google.com/download/ios