# Xcode gives plenty of Undefined Symbol: Firebase_App error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I Build my Unity project to Xcode, trying to install it on ios device. It gives errors like as follow

```
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_GetApps
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_App_CSharp_FirebaseApp_RegisterLibrariesInternal
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_AdditionalUserInfoInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_CredentialInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_UserInternal_get
> 
> Undefined symbol: _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_AuthResult_UserInternal_set
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordInternalAsync
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordInternalAsync_DEPRECATED
> 
> Undefined symbol:
> _Firebase_Auth_CSharp_FirebaseAuth_SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialInternalAsync
```

totally gives 69 error like this.

I tried to add GameKit.framework, but still continue.

XCode version is: 14.3.1 (14E300c)
Firebase pod versions: 10.12.0, also I tried with 10.11.0 and 10.10.0
minimum ios version is:12.0
Unity Version is: 2021.3.16.
Firebase Unity SDK is: 11.1.0

and my podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 16.0'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseCore', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseDatabase', '10.11.0'
  pod 'FirebaseStorage', '10.11.0'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
use_frameworks!
```

Can anyone assist me on this.

Comment: Can you get the Xcode build? Did you try Archive? Is this a runtime error or a build error on the Xcode?

Comment: I get when I trying to install on my device from Xcode. Also I get these errors trying to create archive file.

Comment: did you try `pod repo update` and `pod install` on the terminal while inside your Xcode project path?

Comment: Yes,, I tried it

Comment: It still feels like a pod library error or a library linking error. Maybe you can try these solutions [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292090/firebase-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

upgraded firebase plugin in Unity to 11.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I also face same error few days ago. Irrespective of your pod file there will be some dll present in your project that trying to call old methods. So either you update your dll files or delete unwanted dll files.

Comment: This note an answer it's a comment. Please use comments area