# Xcode 8 Dependency Analysis Warning

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm trying to remove these warnings that show up in xcode(8.3):

```
warning: using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES' while building targets which define modules ('DEFINES_MODULE = YES') may fail. Please migrate to using 'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO'.
```

When I change `'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS'` to `NO` in the Target's Build Settings, the warnings disappear.  But then I get additional warnings when I run `pod install`:

```
[!] The `AppName [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName/Pods-AppName.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Sure enough, when I look in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppName/Pods-AppName.release.xcconfig`, `ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = YES` is there and I'm not sure how it got there or where that file came from.

Does anyone know how to get rid of these errors?  Thanks.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26077106/3901620

Comment: I've tried that, but but inherited value is `YES` so I still get the same xcode warnings.

Comment: which version of xcode are you used now ?

Comment: version 8.3, mentioned it above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode 8.3, that ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS is **now deprecated**:

The "Always Search User Paths" build setting is deprecated and may not be supported by a future version of Xcode. Projects which are relying on this feature should migrate to separate user vs. system header include semantics and set this build setting to "No". (16364329)

Check 
 : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Answer (score 4):

Since the Xcode 8.3 release, the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS is now deprecated, but other libraries that which are still using the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS are putting the setting value in your project, you will have to wait for other libraries make their changes too.

For example, current Core Plot is on version 2.2, it still put the ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS value in my project, the fix for this warning will be released in version 2.3