# Sencha/PhoneGap build error when using CocoaPods to incorporate Firebase Cloud Messaging on iOS

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, phonegap, sencha-cmd

I am trying to get push notifications working on my iOS application (using Sencha cmd and PhoneGap's packaging tools to build the app). Currently when I try to send my iPhone a message from the Firebase Console, I don't receive anything (neither the notification or any errors) despite the status of the message being sent according to Firebase.

I am using:

- Xcode 8.3.2
- Sencha cmd 6.5.1.240
- PhoneGap 7.0.0

So far I have:

- Installed the `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin.
- Installed **CocoaPods**.
- Created an **App ID**, **APNs certificate**, and a **provisioning profile**. The certificate is uploaded to my Firebase app, and the provisioning profile is set up in my Xcode project.
- Enabled **Push Notification** and **Background Mode** capabilities in Xcode.
- Added the generated **GoogleService-Info.plist** to my Xcode project

The error that is happening when trying to build (`sencha app build`) is:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] ** BUILD FAILED **
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript] The following build commands failed:
[INF] [shellscript]     Ld build/emulator/myApp.app/myApp normal x86_64
[INF] [shellscript] Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/iMac/Documents/MyApplication/app/myApp/phonegap/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,myApp.xcworkspace,-scheme,myApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/iMac/Documents/MyApplication/app/myApp/phonegap/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/iMac/Documents/MyApplication/app/myApp/phonegap/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
[INF] [shellscript] 
[INF] [shellscript]
```

I think the issue might be with my Podfile or the way it installs pods - if I remove all of the pods as well as `use_frameworks!` the build finishes successfully and the app can be launched on an iPhone or and emulator in Xcode successfully too.

The Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'myApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end
```

If I include `use_frameworks!` the terminal returns the following when doing `pod install` (the app will also fail to build with the same error as above):

```
[!] The myApp [Debug] target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myApp/Pods-myApp.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the $(inherited) flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The myApp [Release] target overrides the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-myApp/Pods-myApp.release.xcconfig. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the $(inherited) flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

In regards to the above error (when including `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile): I've tried [what was suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods) but if I'm not mistaken, I already have the `$(inherited)` flag:
[Screenshot of my current Other Linker Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAPzJ.png)

I have also tried using the `cordova-plugin-cocoapods-support` plugin to handle the pods but I experience the same errors as above when adding pods through the config.xml rather than manually in the Podfile.

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the app building now both with Sencha cmd and in Xcode.

I'm not 100% certain that this alone was the solution; I was tweaking other things as well. The last thing that I did that caused it to build successfully was `pod deintegrate` and then rebuild the app with the `cordova-plugin-cocoapods-support` plugin handling the pods.

My podfile now looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'myApp' do
    pod 'Firebase', :subspecs => ['release','debug']
    pod 'Firebase/Core', :subspecs => ['release','debug']
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', :subspecs => ['release','debug']
end
```