# React Native Podfile IOS Installation Error

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile

My friend and I have been working in a `react-native` project for a company where he is working on a windows for Android and I am working on IOS part beside `Google Maps` and `PlacesPicker`.
 But now after my friend have added `googleSignin` I try to add it to my `Podfile` for IOS and install the pod there is a error which is stopping me to work on it any more.

```
[!] The `Project [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Project/Pods-Project.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your tips @csath you really helped me to dig down the path file on my xcode .But the issue is actually resolved by @SamirChenon [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30099524/8817388) which I applied to every path. Additionally, I also removed spaces between my `pod packages` in inside `podfile` and `pod install`.

Thank you all for helping :D

Answer (score 2):

Go to Xcode project and select Build settings.
Scroll down and find Library Search Path dropdown under 'Search Paths' section.
In Release mode use $(inherited)in the beginning of the path string.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for a late respond @csath and yes $(inherited) is there in the first line of release when i double click .I dont think I need to add in-front of every line , Or Do I  ?

Comment: No, If it is available there only once it would be fine.

Comment: Yes, Every path includes  $(inherited) in their first line.But I still have the same error .

Comment: Thank man the problem is resolved now . It because of your answer i followed all my path file to double check it .