# Compilation IOS app under XCODE with Firebase notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Good morning all,

I come to you for a problem during the compilation of my application for IOS, It is the first time that I use Xcode.

During compilation I encounter the following problem: ld: framework not found FBLPromises
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I followed the instructions from firebase to integrate it into my application. I notably installed COCOAPOD and created the Podfile file with the following instructions:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
# Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

# Add the pods for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
target 'iOS Push' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for iOS Push

end
```

No matter how much I search the internet for the same problem, I can't help but solve this problem. I already tried to reintegrate pot and redo Install podium and lots of other manipulation but still this problem.

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you followed all this steps, that are necessary to use the Firebase framework in your project:

1. Install Cocoapds to your Mac
2. Create your Podfile in your project folder (with `pod init`)
3. Add the Firebase pods you want to use to your Podfile
4. Create a iOS project in Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) and link it to your app, using your bundle identifier
5. Download the GoogleService-Info.plist provided from firebase console when creating the link and add it to your Xcode project
6. Install the pod in your project folder using `pod install`

If you did  everything correctly, you should see a `.xcworkspace` in your project folder, which you should use from now on (instead of the normal `.xcodeproj`).

Comment: I now have this error message: ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You pod file should be setup like this.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'iOS Push' do
# Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for iOS Push
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

end
```

You added your pods outside of 'iOS Push' target. Also as @Maria Fernanda Azolin mentioned, use .xcworkspace after pod installation

Comment: I still get the same error message that appears. I did not specify that I develop this application under windev mobile.

Comment: I now have this error message: ld: library not found for -lBoringSSL-GRPC clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) –

Comment: A solution to give? I tried to reinstall everything and I have the same error as at the beginning, I do not master XCode and I may search the internet I do not know how to solve this problem that it can not find the library.

Comment: Does blank project with firebase setup be ok? I can create blank project with firebase pods building right on git. You can compare them or if it does not build than something else is issue.

Comment: Also can you provide me the instruction link you followed?

Comment: I followed this documentation but applying what I need

Comment: Here is the documentation link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: I don't mind trying to create a blank project with Firebase and the following in the Podfile:

`# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics 
'Firebase / Analytics' pod
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods`

Comment: I tried the steps. It built as expected. Also I added 'pod 'Firebase/Messaging'' for push notification. Did you open .xcodeproj file after pod install? You should always open .xcworkspace (white icon file) after pod install. I hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, I still can't do it. You can send me your project by email so that I compare with mine to find out what's wrong? I thank you in advance.

Comment: I just realized that I had not integrated the initialization code in the project. This code given by Firebase is obviously not compatible with xcode.

`@import UIKit;
@import Firebase;

@implementation WDAppDelegate

- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}`

XCODE does not recognize this code when I integrate it in WDAppDelegate is this the source of my problem maybe?

Comment: https://github.com/saminadhikari/iOS-push-firebase-test
pod install first. I am using Swift. Looks like you're using objective C but the setup is similar anyway

Comment: Thank you very much for your project, indeed it works very well. I tried on mine with the same Podfile, nothing to do it can not find Firebase. I noticed on my project that it appears in the terminal of the information which does not appear when I made pod install with your project, the problem comes from it?

Comment: [!] The `CRE Pays de la Loire [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: [!] The `CRE Pays de la Loire [Debug]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: [!] The `CRE Pays de la Loire [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: [!] The `CRE Pays de la Loire [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire/Pods-CRE Pays de la Loire.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

Comment: I think this is some build setting issue on xcode. Maybe https://developpaper.com/cocoapod-target-overrides-the-other_ldflags-the-solution-of/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376416/the-target-overrides-the-other-ldflags-build-setting-defined-in-pods-pods can help. But incase this does not help. Starting new project and adding storyboards/files from old project can be time saver. Messed up build settings can be hard to fix sometimes :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. The problem comes from that for framwork not found. I added an ObjeC file in the project with the initialization code of Firebase, the app builds correctly. Firebase recognizes that the application is installed and communicated, but I don't receive any notification even using my project and replacing the google.plist file. What can this come from?

Comment: Try using these steps https://mobikul.com/send-push-notification-via-firebase-ios-postman/ .

Comment: I tried with an old script that I have for Firebase and Android, I put the token that I receive from my application but obviously it does not work. Is there a notification receipt code to put in addition somewhere?